# Openssl generate invalid websocket security code

Tags: shell, hashsum, here-string

I need to write websocket server on GAWK. And server must handle user's Sec-WebSocket-Key by following algorithm (from RFC):

1. Concat key with `258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11`
2. Take sha-1 in binary form (should have 20 symbols)
3. Take base64 from that binary form

I'm trying to use openssl but the resulting code is incorrect:

```
$ openssl sha1 -binary <<< 'a0+ZvgYqsMFHRerif0go8g==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11' | openssl base64
mYryklMdRrrLwrMQDeKEzOVMMWk=
```

Meanwhile, the following PHP code generates valid output:

```
$key = "a0+ZvgYqsMFHRerif0go8g==";
$hash = $key.'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'; 
$hash = sha1($hash,true);
$hash = base64_encode($hash); 
echo($hash);
```

tswGtNOxrRhDmC04XQaDigMeaJA=

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, -n for echo and it's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The here string construct `<<<…` feeds the given string *plus a newline* as input to the command. So `openssl sha1 -binary <<< 'a0+ZvgYqsMFHRerif0go8g==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'` is equivalent to

```
printf '%s\n' 'a0+ZvgYqsMFHRerif0go8g==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11' | openssl sha1 -binary
```

But your specification says “Concat key with 258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11”, not “Concat[enate the] key with 258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11 and a newline”. So you need

```
printf '%s' 'a0+ZvgYqsMFHRerif0go8g==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11' | openssl sha1 -binary
```

and this does produce `tswGtNOxrRhDmC04XQaDigMeaJA=`.

`echo -n …` is equivalent to `printf %s …` except that there are shells that don't support `echo -n` or that expand backslash escapes in `echo …`, whereas `printf %s …` has a standard behavior (always print the argument literally).